# Faster memory allocation and freeing algorithm than multiple Free List method

Tags: algorithm, heap-memory

We allocate and free many memory blocks. We use [Memory Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP). However, heap access is costly.

For faster memory access allocation and freeing, we adopt a global [Free List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list). As we make a multithreaded program, the Free List is protected by a [Critical Section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section). However, Critical Section causes a bottleneck in parallelism.

For removing the Critical Section, we assign a Free List for each thread, i.e. [Thread Local Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage). However, thread T1 always memory blocks and thread T2 always frees them, so Free List in thread T2 is always increasing, meanwhile there is no benefit of Free List.

Despite of the bottleneck of Critical Section, we adopt the Critical Section again, with some different method. We prepare several Free Lists as well as Critical Sections which is assigned to each Free List, thus 0~N-1 Free Lists and 0~N-1 Critical Sections. We prepare an [atomic-operated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/interlocked-variable-access) integer value which mutates to 0, 1, 2, ... N-1 then 0, 1, 2, ... again. For each allocation and freeing, we get the integer value X, then mutate it, access X-th Critical Section, then access X-th Free List. However, this is quite slower than the previous method (using Thread Local Storage). Atomic operation is quite slow as there are more threads.

As mutating the integer value non-atomically cause no corruption, we did the mutation in non-atomic way. However, as the integer value is sometimes stale, there is many chance of accessing the same Critical Section and Free List by different threads. This causes the bottleneck again, though it is quite few than the previous method.

Instead of the integer value, we used thread ID with hashing to the range (0~N-1), then the performance got better.

I guess there must be much better way of doing this, but I cannot find an exact one. Are there any ideas for improving what we have made?

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with heap memory is a task for the OS. Nothing guarantees you can do a better/faster job than the OS does.

But there are some conditions where you can get a bit of improvement, specially when you know something about your memory usage that is unknown to the OS.
I'm writting here my untested idea, hope you'll get some profit of it.

Let's say you have T threads, all of them reserving and freeing memory. The main goal is speed, so I'll try not to use TLS, nor critical blocking, not atomic ops.

If (repeat: if, if, if) the app can fit to several discrete sizes of memory blocks (not random sizes, so as to avoid fragmentation and unuseful holes) then start asking the OS for a number of these discrete blocks.

For example, you have an array of `n1` blocks each of size `size1`, an array of `n2` blocks each of size `size2`, an array of `n3`... and so on. Each array is bidimensional, the second field just stores a flag for used/free block. If your arrays are very large then it's better to use a dedicated array for the flags (due to contiguous memory usage is always faster).

Now, some one asks for a block of memory of size `sB`. A specialized function (or object or whatever) searches the array of blocks of size greater or equal to `sB`, and then selects a block by looking at the used/free flag. Just before ending this task the proper block-flag is set to "used".

When two or more threads ask for blocks of the same size there may be a corruption of the flag. Using TLS will solve this issue, and critical blocking too. I think you can set a bool flag at the beggining of the search into flags-array, that makes the other threads to wait until the flag changes, which only happens after the block-flag changes. With pseudo code:

```
MemoryGetter(sB)
{
    //select which array depending of 'sB'
    for (i=0, i < numOfarrays, i++)
        if (sizeOfArr(i) >= sB)
           arrMatch = i
           break //exit for

    //wait if other thread wants a block from the same arrMatch array
    while ( searching(arrMatch) == true )
        ; //wait
    //blocks other threads wanting a block from the same arrMatch array
    searching(arrMatch) = true

    //Get the first free block
    for (i=0, i < numOfBlocks, i++)
        if ( arrOfUsed(arrMatch, i) != true )
           selectedBlock = addressOf(....)
           //mark the block as used
           arrOfUsed(arrMatch, i) = true
           break; //exit for

     //Allow other threads
     searching(arrMatch) = false

     return selectedBlock  //NOTE: selectedBlock==NULL means no free block
}
```

Freeing a block is easier, just mark it as free, no thread concurrency issue.

Dealing with no free blocks is up to you (wait, use a bigger block, ask OS for more, etc).

Note that the whole memory is reserved from the OS at app start, which can be a problem.

If this idea makes your app faster, let me know. What I can say for sure is that memory used is greater than if you use normal OS request; but not much if you choose "good" sizes, those most used.

Some improvements can be done:

- Cache the last freeded block (per size) so as to avoid the search.
- Start with not that much blocks, and ask the OS for more memory only
  when needed. Play with 'number of blocks' for each size depending on
  your app. Find the optimal case.